# Ansible 2.7.x skipping task: "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible is skipping the execution of a task even when my conditional string is meeting the requirement and I can see this string in the stdout.

1. I tried playing around with the content option in copy module where I replaced {{inventory_hostname}} with {{ansible_host}}
2. I tried replacing result.stdout_lines with result.stdout as the stdout output is a dictionary.

```
---
- name: Detecting NXOS 5K devices which fail the 'copy run start' from device inventory
  hosts: nxos-5k
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  tasks:

    - name: Gather device specific facts
      nxos_facts:
        gather_subset: config
      register: net_facts


    - name: Executing 'copy run start' on NXOS 5K chassis
      nxos_command:
        commands:
           - 'copy run start'
      register: result
      ignore_errors: True
    - debug: var=result.stdout_lines

    - name: Copy the device name to failed device list
      copy:
        content: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
        dest: /home/saurasar/ansibledev/results/failed_nxos_devices.txt
      when: "'Configuration update aborted: request was aborted' in result.stdout_lines"
```

Expected result: String search should be successful as I can see from -vvv that result.stdout contains the string.

```
 "stdout_lines": [[0m
[0;32m            [[0m
[0;32m                "[#                                       ]   1%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#                                       ]   2%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##                                      ]   3%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##                                      ]   4%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###                                     ]   5%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###                                     ]   6%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###                                     ]   7%", [0m
[0;32m                "[####                                    ]   8%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#####                                   ]  10%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#####                                   ]  11%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#####                                   ]  12%", [0m
[0;32m                "[######                                  ]  13%", [0m
[0;32m                "[######                                  ]  14%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#######                                 ]  15%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#######                                 ]  16%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#######                                 ]  17%", [0m
[0;32m                "[########                                ]  19%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#########                               ]  20%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#########                               ]  21%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#########                               ]  22%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##########                              ]  23%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##########                              ]  24%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###########                             ]  25%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###########                             ]  26%", [0m
[0;32m                "[############                            ]  28%", [0m
[0;32m                "[############                            ]  29%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#############                           ]  30%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#############                           ]  31%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#############                           ]  32%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##############                          ]  33%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##############                          ]  34%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###############                         ]  35%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###############                         ]  37%", [0m
[0;32m                "[################                        ]  38%", [0m
[0;32m                "[################                        ]  39%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#################                       ]  40%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#################                       ]  41%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#################                       ]  42%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##################                      ]  43%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##################                      ]  44%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###################                     ]  46%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###################                     ]  47%", [0m
[0;32m                "[####################                    ]  48%", [0m
[0;32m                "[####################                    ]  49%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#####################                   ]  50%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#####################                   ]  51%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#####################                   ]  52%", [0m
[0;32m                "[######################                  ]  53%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#######################                 ]  55%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#######################                 ]  56%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#######################                 ]  57%", [0m
[0;32m                "[########################                ]  58%", [0m
[0;32m                "[########################                ]  59%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#########################               ]  60%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#########################               ]  61%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#########################               ]  62%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##########################              ]  64%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###########################             ]  65%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###########################             ]  66%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###########################             ]  67%", [0m
[0;32m                "[############################            ]  68%", [0m
[0;32m                "[############################            ]  69%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#############################           ]  70%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#############################           ]  71%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##############################          ]  73%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##############################          ]  74%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###############################         ]  75%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###############################         ]  76%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###############################         ]  77%", [0m
[0;32m                "[################################        ]  78%", [0m
[0;32m                "[################################        ]  79%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#################################       ]  80%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#################################       ]  82%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##################################      ]  83%", [0m
[0;32m                "[##################################      ]  84%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###################################     ]  85%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###################################     ]  86%", [0m
[0;32m                "[###################################     ]  87%", [0m
[0;32m                "[####################################    ]  88%", [0m
[0;32m                "[####################################    ]  89%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#####################################   ]  91%", [0m
[0;32m                "[#####################################   ]  92%", [0m
[0;32m                "[######################################  ]  93%", [0m
[0;32m                "[######################################  ]  94%", [0m
[0;32m                "[####################################### ]  95%", [0m
[0;32m                "[####################################### ]  96%", [0m
[0;32m                "[####################################### ]  97%", [0m
[0;32m                "[########################################]  98%", [0m
[0;32m                "[########################################] 100%", [0m
[0;32m                "Copy complete, now saving to disk (please wait)..."[0m
```

Actual result:

```
TASK [Copy the device name to failed device list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/saurasar/ansibledev/failure.detection.2.yml:22
skipping: [Device hostname] => {
    "changed": false,
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. If I create a variable with the content from your question, the task runs as expected. Can you post a complete, runnable playbook that demonstrates the problem? Ideally, just embed the content in the `vars` section rather than relying on an external command.

Comment: Take care that `'abc' in ['abc ', 'def']` would result in false (because of the space in the array first element) when `'abc' in "abc \ndef"` would result in true, because it ends up being a substring search. So possibly, if this comes from an hidden character (explaining why @larsks was not able to reproduce, neither I) `when: "'Configuration update aborted: request was aborted' in result.stdout"`, could work

Comment: @larsks I just added the complete playbook if that helps.

Comment: @b.enoit.be That makes sense. What should I try instead then?

Comment: maybe what you can try is to do something like `./whatevere_command | cat -A` in a basic shell to eliminate the possibility of hidden char anywhere in the output of the said command

Comment: By "...that demonstrates the problem", I meant something that if we were to download it, without requiring any special equipment, we could reproduce the problem, because you embedded test data in the playbook. As @b.enoit.be said, it's probably something in the output that you're missing, and without access to the *actual output* from your nxos device there's not much we can do.  @b.enoit.be's idea of checking against `stdout` instead of `stdout_lines` is a good one.

Comment: After some more trying, I found another way and looks like that fixed the problem! I just added [0] at the end of stdout and it did the trick. when: "'Configuration update aborted: request was aborted' in result.stdout_lines[0]"

Comment: thanks guys @b.enoit.be and larsks.

Comment: Meaning you get an array in `stdout_lines` and need to search a value in an array of array. The **full** debug statement of your command result would have us getting that. Since the answer is impossible to guess from your question, I am voting to close as such.

Comment: agreed @b.enoit.be. The output of stdout_lines was enormous and I wasn't sure earlier that I could post all of it in my question. I edited the section to add the full output. Thx again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After some more trying, I found another way and looks like that fixed the problem! I just added [0] at the end of stdout and it did the trick. when: "'Configuration update aborted: request was aborted' in result.stdout_lines[0]"